# Forest loss per year inside protected areas in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to extract forest loss data between 2001 and 2015 inside protected areas (PA) in the Democratic Republic of the Congo. I want to send this data as a CSV file to my drive with each row showing the amount of deforestation (in m2) in PAs for that year. When I run the code in different versions, it varies from crashing to sending wrongly formatted CSV files to my drive. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong/how I could optimise my code. The latest iteration is found below.

Link to EE Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c0df34d45c1cf64c5d88cba396b93d2c

```js
// Load country boundaries from LSIB.

    var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

// Get a feature collection with just the Country feature.

    var country = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CF'));


//Select only PA polygons within specified country

        var protectedareas = wdpa.filter(ee.Filter.lt('STATUS_YR', 2016));
    var AOI = protectedareas.filterBounds(country.first().geometry());

// Get the loss image.

    var gfc2017 = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2017_v1_5');
    var lossImage = gfc2017.select(['lossyear']);
    var lossAreaImage = lossImage.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());


    var lossYear = gfc2017.select(['lossyear']);
    var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossYear).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
        groupField: 1
        }),
      geometry: AOI,
      scale: 30,
      maxPixels: 1e10
    });

    var statsFormatted = ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
      .map(function(el) {
        var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
        return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
      });
    var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());
    print(statsDictionary);
    
    var Name = country + 'forestloss';

    var allstats = [
      ee.Feature(null, {'prop': statsDictionary}),
    ];

    Export.table.toDrive({
        'collection': ee.FeatureCollection(allstats),
        'description': Name,
        'folder':'GEE_exports',
        'fileFormat': 'CSV'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with your code:

1. `var Name`, an approach to fix it:

```
var Name = (country.first().get("country_na")).getInfo() + '_forestloss';
```

2. For export, I will suggest:

```
// Construct a table to export by rows.
var year_and_area = statsDictionary.keys().zip(statsDictionary.values());
var datatable = ee.FeatureCollection(year_and_area.map(function (year_and_area) {
  var year_index = ee.List(year_and_area).get(0);
  var area_year = ee.List(year_and_area).get(1);
  return ee.Feature(null).set('year', year_index,'area', area_year);
}));

Export.table.toDrive({
    'collection':datatable,
    'description': Name,
    'folder':'GEE_exports',
    'fileFormat': 'CSV'
});
```

here the [codelink](https://code.earthengine.google.com/68181505dff0e483000e78453c63c419)